# Version of Oracle thin driver to use with Java 6

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle10g, java-6, java-ee-5

We are upgrading from Java 1.5 to Java 6 and J2EE 1.4 to Java EE 5. We are using Oracle 10g. Java EE 5 only supports JDBC 3.0, but Java 6 supports JDBC 4.0. If I am running on a Java EE 5 server with Java 6, can I use the JDBC 4.0 API in my Java EE 5 web app?

Which Oracle thin driver should I use? Is it `ojdbc6.jar` from [Oracle's download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-111060-084321.html)? Is that compatible with Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ojdbc6.jar`.

There are 3 Oracle JDBC drivers still being widely used:

- `ojdbc14.jar` for projects with JDK 1.4
- `ojdbc5.jar` for projects with JDK 5 (or 1.5)
- `ojdbc6.jar` for projects with JDK 6 (or 1.6)

Even though you're using Java EE 5, if the relevant JDK is 6, then you match Oracle driver's version number with your JDK number.

Oracle has a FAQ on their JDBC drivers regarding driver and database compatibility. [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_02) part might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 10g [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html) is the list of available JDBC drivers.
The list does not contain a specific driver for JDK 1.6, the latest version is ojdbc14.jar  what I suspect you have already used.

Your have referred to Oracle 11g JDBC drivers which may also work with Oracle 10g but I have no experience with that.